# VLOOKUP won't work unless text is retyped manually even after cleaning and trimming

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have been having this problem with the VLOOKUP function lately. I have two arrays with mostly the same data in the first column and I'm trying to stitch them together using VLOOKUP as I've always done.

However, VLOOKUP always returns #N/A, despite the key existing in the second array, unless the data in the first array is rewritten by hand. I have cleaned and trimmed the data in both arrays to try to fix it. I have formatted the relevant columns appropriately (they're both text strings). I have cleared formats, comments and notes, hyperlinks, everything. Please please help, I'm at a loss!

Here is the function I'm using:

```
(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

Here is an example of the two arrays:

| Player | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Cade Cunningham | #N/A |
| Jordan Nwora | #N/A |
| Luka Doncic | #N/A |

| Player | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Jordan Nwora | 1.5 |
| Luka Doncic | 1.3 |
| Cade Cunningham | 2.1 |

Comment: Could you edit the question with your VLOOKUP function?

Comment: @Randomhero just done, thank you for noting that!

Comment: VLOOKUP looks for data in order of apperanace. It always finds the first match, and it used to be a requirement to sort the table too for an optimal VLOOKUP.

Comment: What is the source for the first array? Is it copied from some other place/document into the cells? There might be a hidden Enter character in the cell in source.  Try this formula. =VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""),Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)

Comment: Did you copy/paste from your Excel into the table you posted?  Try doing that as that might carry over some of these errant characters that are causing VLOOKUP  to return the error.

Comment: [Jeorje's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1685202/348859) is good but you may also be interested in [ways to remove all non-alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29149916/4475014), especially [Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888907/4475014).

Answer (score 2):

The telling point made is `unless the data in the first array is rewritten by hand`:  this means, to about a five sigma certainty, that there are still non-happy characters in the strings, even after trimming and cleaning.

Even without that point, this would almost certainly be the case given the steps you have taken.

I would especially direct attention to the fact that non-printing characters are often non-visible as well, except to someone looking, carefully, for precisely them.

They literally take no actual space in the line of text you see when you enter the formula editor (with <kbd>F2</kbd>, say). They simply do not seem to exist, visible in no way whatsoever except for one physical test. One can use other tests, formulas for instance, but physically, only the "arrow" test is effective.

For that, enter Edit mode (<kbd>F2</kbd>) on one such cell that is giving an error when its value is looked up. Note the cursor at the end of the text in the cell. Or click at the end to have it start there. Using the <kbd>←</kbd> key, slowly, or at least carefully, move toward the start of the text. What you are looking for is a moment when the key is pressed, but the cursor doesn't move left. Oops, must've not quite pressed it. No, you pressed it, it's just that you found one of the characters giving you trouble.

At this point, and if it is as one hopes, that there is just a single such character occurring throughout the data, not several, you can move the cursor over the next character to be sure of your place, then back, then move it one more character rightward but with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed, note that it seems not to move again, then one more character noting it gets highlighted too, then back left so it unhighlights. You should now have only the invisible character highlighted. Copy it to the Clipboard.

Exit the cell, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up `Find and Replace`, and replace all instances of this character by pasting it into the `Find what:` entry line.

See if some or all of the lookups now provide good answers. If "all", then that my be all you need to do. If only "some", there are more to find in the continued error-return pieces of data.

You can select some empty cell, enter `Edit Mode`, and paste this character into it. Then in another cell, use the `UNICODE()` function (NOT the `CODE()` function) to get is decimal code. You can record that for use on future downloads of the data.

Using Excel's `CLEAN()` function especially, or finding sites recommending you also `Find and Replace` a short list of characters, doesn't really work well. The `CLEAN()` function was like a version 1.0 (or 0.7...) on the idea and has never been updated. The lists you find are like a version 2.0, or so, in that they were the characters websites started using after programs got functionality like Excel's `CLEAN()` function. For whatever reason, website programmers do not want you removing these characters so they keep using new ones. I won't say they are trying to screw us when we "screen scrape" but it does come to mind. More likely they are trying to stay ahead of

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most frustrating Excel problems!
99% of the time, if the data is there it's probably down to either extra spaces in the lookup cell or formatting.

Using trim(*cell ref*) will normally cure the spaces.

the formatting is a little trickier...
one workaround that I normally use is:

Format the lookup cells as Text,
Highlight and Copy the lookup cells,
Go to desktop and open a new text document,
Paste the data into the text document(Ctrl C)
Highlight the pasted data (Ctrl A)
Copy and paste it back into the sheet (Ctrl C) go to sheet (Ctrl V)

this should get your lookup working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I used trim(text) -as suggested in the link below- within the Vlookup function and worked! Otherwise it didn't.

https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/troubleshooting-vlookup/

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please see the [guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) on answering in the [Help center](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). You need to add the actual steps of the solution in the answer; link-only answers get [deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). I'd recommend checking the Asking and Answering sections in the Help, and reviewing some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to see how the site works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177246)

Answer (score 0):

**Explantion**

In Excel, VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP both assume that they are searching for keys in an alphabetically sorted list.

If while searching for a key ("John" for example), it comes across another key that is alphabetically after what is looking for ("Ryan" for example) then it will quit searching early and return the value from the row above.

If the key being searched for is alphabetically before the first key in the list then it will always return "#N/A".

**Examples**

So if I was searching for "Kendrick James" (or anything alphabetically after "Jordan Nwora" and before "Luka Doncic") in the first column of your second array, then it will return 1.5.

If you ever search for "Cade Cunningham" it will never find it because it will quit early on "Jordan Nwora". Additionally, in this case it will return "#N/A" because it quit on the first item in the list.

This example picture of a spreadsheet that I just made explains it really well.
[image: This example picture of a spreadsheet that I just made explains it really well.]

This is not well documented on the Microsoft Excel formula website. I have run into it a number of times though.

Hope this helps!!